# Get windows users with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-users

How can I get a list of all windows users of the local machine with the usage of .NET (C#) ?

Comment: You say `of a specific machine`, do you mean the local/actual machine or from a machine on the network?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of local computer usernames in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247798/get-list-of-local-computer-usernames-in-windows)

Answer (score 11):

Here is a blog post (with code) that explains how to do it:

http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-get-list-of-windows-user-in-c.html

The author lists the following code (quoted from the above site):

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("users","group");
object members = admGroup.Invoke("members", null);
foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
{
    DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember);
    lstUsers.Items.Add(member.Name);
}
```

You need to add  `using System.DirectoryServices` at the top of your code.  To change machines, you would change the `Environment.MachineName` to be whatever machine you want to access (as long as you have permission to do so and the firewall isn't blocking you from doing so).  I also modified the author's code to look at the `users` group instead of the `administrators` group.

Comment: Any idea how reliable it is? i.e. there are alternatives using WMI claiming it can be used without issues, but it has a failure rate > 0.5%

Comment: In my experience, this method is reliable.  As far as how reliable, I can't speak to that.  It should be totally reliable.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are really 'after'... if you are on a windows domain (using active directory) then you can query [Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/activedirquery.aspx) *IF* active directory is being used to limit the users who are "authorized" to use the local machine.

If your requirements are not as stringent then you can inspect the folders in the system UserProfiles where each folder *except* Default User and All Users represent a user profile that has logged into the local machine. **caution** this may include system and/or service accounts...