# C# finding all Microsoft Accounts on machine

Tags: c#, powershell, directoryservices, microsoft-account, principalsearcher

I am trying to get the UPN and Microsoft Accounts for all users on my machine using C#.

I am currently logged into an Azure account, and `whoami` returns details as expected and that I am looking for (but for all users):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> whoami /upn
my.name@mydomain.com
PS C:\Windows\system32> whoami
corp\my.name
```

The below C# code only returns users in `Comuter Management` mmc:

```
var searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher();
var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine));
searcher.QueryFilter = userPrincipal;
var results = searcher.FindAll();
```

[image: computer mangement]

The [powershell function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) `Get-LocalUser | Select-Object Name,PrincipalSource` seems not to provide more info either, despite saying it supports Microsoft Accounts:

```
Name               PrincipalSource
----               ---------------
Administrator                Local
DefaultAccount               Local
Guest                        Local
WDAGUtilityAccount           Local
```

As a final step to get the user by SID, by finding the SID profile @ `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and using this with:

```
Get-localUser -SID S-1-12-1-1111111141-1234567891-3802628514-1659616000
Get-localUser : User S-1-12-1-1111111141-1234567891-3802628514-1659616000 was not found.
```

I have tried running as admin also and get the same output - pointers on how to get Microsoft Accounts with C# (or Powershell which i can then call via C#) much appreciated.

Comment: Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033391/get-windows-users-with-c-sharp