# C# program to list the users and their respective paths to their directories

Tags: c#, windows

I wish to is there any way in C# as a program to find out the list of users available in the  system i,e in My computer  and the path to their directories. i mean to say suppose there are 2 users

"User A" and "User B"

And their path I mean the User A's all the documents will be in D:\Documents and Settings\User A
and similarly for User B.

Is there any way in C# to find out the list of users and the paths to their respective directories.

Comment: mp3duck, with the example paths in the question and the [tag:windows] tag ... that's kind of obvious, isn't it?

Comment: too early.. didn't spot the windows tag! :(

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247798/get-list-of-local-computer-usernames-in-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
string users_reg_key=
   @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DocFolderPaths";

public string[] ListWinUsersList()
{
 //The registry key for reading user list.

 RegistryKey key =
 Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(users_reg_key, true);

 string[] winusers = "  ".Split(' ');//this resolve problem with assigned variable

 if (key != null && key.ValueCount > 0)
 {
     winusers = key.GetValueNames();
 }
 return winusers;
}
```

**EDIT**

to get directory try something like this

```
string path =  Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).FullName;
if ( Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 ) {
 path = Directory.GetParent(path);
}
```

Comment: Will it be generic I mean for windows 7 and windows xp ?