# c# Delete file in all user in profile

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, environment-variables

I am creating an application that put file in user profile. Now, i want to upgrade that file, the problem is, how to find the file that is in the other user profile. I know we can expand environmental variables, but it will only expand the current user only.

Example:
The file I create is in %USERPROFILE%\MyApplicationName\Directory\FileIWantToAccess

but then, this application is can be run by many user. Using expand user profile is not helping.
so, if we have 2 user or more:
UserA\MyApplicationName\Directory\FileIWantToAccess
UserB\MyApplicationName\Directory\FileIWantToAccess

if i run it as user Admin, i want to delete all of them, how to find/delete/move them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247798/get-list-of-local-computer-usernames-in-windows) you can get the windows users list, and then add it to your address to delete it

```
foreach(string userName in userList)
    File.Delete(userName+@"\MyApplicationName\Directory\FileIWantToAccess\YouFileName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing this update at the next startup of the application.

Consider a redirected user profile, even if you are a local admin, you still wouldn't have rights to the share.

Or the user has the files locally, but encrypted. In that case you will hit a Security Exception when you try to replace/update the file.

Comment: I can't do that, because i want my application only read from one folder. And that new folder is not in the user profile anymore.