# C# Windows Service Enviroment.GetFolderPath() returning empty string

Tags: c#, windows-services

The question is pretty straight forward, I am making a Windows Service Program and the enviroment.getfolderpath isnt working.

Here is the code I have

```
string savePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // this works
string savePath2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); // this returns an empty string...but why?
```

Comment: What's the Account with which the Service is running? User/LocalSystem/LocalService/NetworkService

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar LocalSystem

Comment: The desktop belonging to a service user is a particularly boring folder, if it even existed. It is *not* the same as the desktop(s) of any user(s) who are currently logged into that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says

> The path to the specified system special folder, if that folder
> physically exists on your computer; otherwise, an empty string ("").A
> folder will not physically exist if the operating system did not
> create it, the existing folder was deleted, or the folder is a virtual
> directory, such as My Computer, which does not correspond to a
> physical path.

When running the Service as a Local System it doesn't run with any specific user permissions. Hence the GetFolderPath is returning empty because it is not able to recognize the path Desktop for LocalSystem.

You can either use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory` which will give `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` or
run the service with a specific user (in my case it's sampleuser) which will give the output as `C:\Users\sampleuser\Desktop`

[image]

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is returning the value because it knows the physical path of the Service.exe. It maybe in user's desktop folder  or in some other location it will always give the output. No dependence with the Account with the service is running.

Comment: The common desktop directory works perfectly, but out of curiosity , you have any idea how I can programmatically select a user account on another computer?

Comment: u can get a list of local users https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247798/get-list-of-local-computer-usernames-in-windows.. but if u have to select user programmatically to run the service.. you cannot.. It has to be configured while installing the service or you can change the LogOn. Once the service is started you cannot change the user for that service