# Get Local User from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to get the local users that are connected to a Microsoft account from my C# application.

```
PS C:\Users\MyUser> Get-LocalUser | Select Name, PrincipalSource
```

When I run this from cmd, I get the desired results.
I tried to reproduce this in c#

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.AddCommand("Get-LocalUser | Select Name, PrincipalSource");
               
                    foreach (PSObject pso in ps.Invoke())
                    {
                        if (pso.Members["PrincipalSource"].Value != null)
                        {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This will return the User name but not the PrincipalSource, there are no return errors

Comment: seems like you're missing some code. Where exactly are you displaying it?

Comment: yes, i removed the code in the "value != null" section, regardless it never hits there

Comment: ... and why do you pass via Powershell? Can't you do this using Windows API?

Comment: Is there documentation for this?

Comment: It looks like you don't need to go via PowerShell: [Get list of local computer usernames in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247798/get-list-of-local-computer-usernames-in-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Select`, just return the whole object back to C#

```cs
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("Get-LocalUser");
               
    foreach (Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LocalUser lu in ps.Invoke())
    {
        if (lu.PrincipalSource != null)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have the module referenced then you can just use `dynamic`

```cs
foreach (dynamic lu in ps.Invoke())
```

Comment: there is no LocalUser type in Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands namespace

Comment: I have the assembly located at `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts.dll"` or you can use late binding with dynamic

Comment: still comes out as null, maybe something to do with running 64 bit?