# how to get logged on users with their status on remote machine

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm looking for a way to get the users that are logged in on a remote machine. I would love to know if they are logged on localy or remotely, but most of all I MUST know their status.
I saw some answers on the net that are written in VB, but I need it in c#.
the solution given in [markdmak answer here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1308179) is looking like a good start, but it's in VB and it looks for remote sessions only.
I have this piece of code, which can be a start, but I would like to couple the LogonId to a username and to see its status:

```
string fqdn = ""; // set!!!    
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.EnablePrivileges = true;
// To connect to the remote computer using a different account, specify these values:
// these are needed in dev environment
options.Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KerberosImpersonationUser"];
options.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KerberosImpersonationPassword"];
options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KerberosImpersonationDomain"];

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + fqdn + "\\root\\CIMV2", options);
try
{
    scope.Connect();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.StartsWith("The RPC server is unavailable"))
    {
        // The Remote Procedure Call server is unavailable
        // cannot check for logged on users
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogonSession");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
bool returnVal = false;
foreach (ManagementObject os in results)
{
    try
    {
        if (os.GetPropertyValue("LogonId").ToString() != null && os.GetPropertyValue("LogonId").ToString() != "")
        {
            returnVal = true;
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
return returnVal;
}
```

What I really need and can't find, is a way of getting ALL users on a remote machine AND their status, meaning: Active, Disconnected, Logged-off, etc.

Comment: you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132620/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-logged-in-connected-users-in-net)?

Comment: FYI, you probably don't want `throw ex;`. Just use `throw;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Win32_LogonSession` WMI class filtering for the [`LogonType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property with the value 2 (Interactive)

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string ComputerName = "remote-machine";
            ManagementScope Scope;

            if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                Conn.Username = "username";
                Conn.Password = "password";
                Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
            }
            else
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

            Scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT LogonId  FROM Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType=2");
            ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

            foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "LogonId", WmiObject["LogonId"]);// String
                ObjectQuery LQuery = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=" + WmiObject["LogonId"] + "} Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent");
                ManagementObjectSearcher LSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, LQuery);
                foreach (ManagementObject LWmiObject in LSearcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "Name", LWmiObject["Name"]);                    
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `LogonType=2` also includes user if it is not logged in but have a process running under its name. Is there a way exclude such users and get a list of "actually" logged in users?

Answer (score 4):

@RRUZ got me started but the `Associators` query did not work on remote machine with a lot of `Win32_LoggedOnUser` objects (don't know why).  No results were returned.

I also needed remote Desktop sessions so I used LogonType "10" sessions and my `ConnectionOptions` were differents

I replaced the Associators query with `WmiObject.GetRelationships("Win32_LoggedOnUser")` and the speed increases by a lot and results were there.

```
    private void btnUnleash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serverName = "serverName";
        foreach (var user in GetLoggedUser(serverName))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(serverName, user);
        }            
    }   

    private List<string> GetLoggedUser(string machineName)
    { 
        List<string> users = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            var scope = GetManagementScope(machineName);
            scope.Connect();
            var Query = new SelectQuery("SELECT LogonId  FROM Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType=10");
            var Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, Query);
            var regName = new Regex(@"(?<=Name="").*(?="")");

            foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject LWmiObject in WmiObject.GetRelationships("Win32_LoggedOnUser"))
                {
                    users.Add(regName.Match(LWmiObject["Antecedent"].ToString()).Value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            users.Add(ex.Message);
        }

        return users;
    }

    private static ManagementScope GetManagementScope(string machineName)
    {
        ManagementScope Scope;

        if (machineName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", "."), GetConnectionOptions());
        else
        {
            Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", machineName), GetConnectionOptions());
        }
        return Scope;
    }

    private static ConnectionOptions GetConnectionOptions()
    {
        var connection = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            EnablePrivileges = true,
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
        };
        return connection;
    }
```