# Get sessions using cassia with username and password

Tags: impersonation, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I have a remote machine and I want to get all logged in user details. I wrote the code using cassia as follwoign using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809906/815600)

```
    ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
    using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer("SERVERIPADDRESS"))
    {
        server.Open();
        foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
        {
            NTAccount account = session.UserAccount;
            string userName = session.UserName;

            if (account != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(account);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to connect to this server using a particular `UserId` and `Password`. How can I do it? I am not getting any option for that.

What I tried is, I gave the server ip address and build the solution. Then I tried the `exe` file as a different user and giving credentials but failed to login.

Can anyone please help. I am ready and open to ditch Cassia, but want a working solution.

And please help me tagging this question, I cant get my mind around it.

Answer (score 3):

As Dan Ports had mentioned, [impersonation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/03/21/400088.aspx) is definitely the way to go.

If, after using impersonation, you're still unable to connect, I found that non-server OSes (ex. Windows 7 or Windows 8.1) need a [registry edit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff710472%28WS.10%29.aspx) at the following location to make Cassia requests work:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer
```

At this location, change the value of **AllowRemoteRPC** to **1**.

Comment: In order to make this a good answer you should complement it with the info in the link. Linked pages change or disappear over time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use impersonation -- the underlying Remote Desktop Services API does not support passing in credentials as parameters. See [Cassia issue 32](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/issues/detail?id=32) and the links in the comments there for more information on impersonation.