# how to Diogenes users that login with remote desktop in windows xp by programming with c#

Tags: windows, authentication, remote-desktop

now i have code that detect session Id of users that connect to Windows with remote desktop (mstsc.exe) to windows XP but i want to know their Usernames.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
    IntPtr hServer,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
    ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
    System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
{
  public Int32 SessionID;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
  public String pWinStationName;

  public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
}

public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
{
  WTSInitialProgram,
  WTSApplicationName,
  WTSWorkingDirectory,
  WTSOEMId,
  WTSSessionId,
  WTSUserName,
  WTSWinStationName,
  WTSDomainName,
  WTSConnectState,
  WTSClientBuildNumber,
  WTSClientName,
  WTSClientDirectory,
  WTSClientProductId,
  WTSClientHardwareId,
  WTSClientAddress,
  WTSClientDisplay,
  WTSClientProtocolType
}
public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
{
  WTSActive,
  WTSConnected,
  WTSConnectQuery,
  WTSShadow,
  WTSDisconnected,
  WTSIdle,
  WTSListen,
  WTSReset,
  WTSDown,
  WTSInit
}
public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
{
  IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
  return server;
}
public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
{
  WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
}
public static DataTable ListUsers(String ServerName)
{
    DataTable DtResult = new DataTable();
    DtResult.Columns.Add("Domain");
    DtResult.Columns.Add("User");

  IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
  List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
  serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

  try
  {
    IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    Int32 sessionCount = 0;
    Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
    Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
    Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
    uint bytes = 0;

    if (retVal != 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
      {
        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        currentSession += dataSize;

        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);
          DtResult.Rows.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) ,Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr));
        WTSFreeMemory(userPtr); 
        WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
      }

      WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    CloseServer(serverHandle);
  }

    return DtResult;
}
```

Comment: use ListUsers(ServerName) method for this goal

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) if you'd like to dealing with the P/Invokes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132620/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-logged-in-connected-users-in-net/809906#809906) for a code sample.