# PowerShell Start Process not working when calling from Remote Machine

Tags: powershell, start-process

I am trying to execute the following powershell script from a Remote machine. It is working fine when running the script locally.

I am able to see the `notepad`, when I execute it from remote machine, I am not able to see any `notepad.exe` process in Task Manager.

**OpenNotepad.ps1:**

```
Start-Process notepad.exe
if($?)
{
write-host "SUCCESS"
}

else
{
write-host "FAIL"
}
```

My Remote Script

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -command "C:\Users\username\Desktop\OpenNotepad.PS1"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748349/powershell-using-start-process-in-pssession-to-open-notepad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Using Start-Process in PSSession to Open Notepad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748349/powershell-using-start-process-in-pssession-to-open-notepad)