# Start application in foreground

Tags: powershell

I have few .net console apps which i want to start remotely using Powershell.

Using `Start-Process` I am able to start the application, however they run in the background so I do not see the app console to check for any error.

Is there a way to run the application in foreground using PS?

Comment: You can use the `-WindowStyle` parameter of the `Start-Process` cmdlet to maximize the process which you have started and bring it to the foreground. For example, `Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized`

Comment: This works from local machine. I am trying using invoke-command to run it from remote machine.

Comment: Apologize for not being clear in the actual post.

Comment: See [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8f4e2ed8-9577-484c-97db-16394c84f912/executing-foreground-task-on-remote-computer?forum=winserverpowershell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748349/powershell-using-start-process-in-pssession-to-open-notepad).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Using Start-Process in PSSession to Open Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748349/powershell-using-start-process-in-pssession-to-open-notepad)