# How to retrieve Sessionname from cassia.dll?

Tags: c#, cassia

I am using cassia library instead of quser for fetching logged on user information from windows (I refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/809906/5182321)

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
    using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer("your-server-name"))
    {
        server.Open();
        foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Session ID: " + session.SessionId);
            Console.WriteLine("User: " + session.UserAccount);
            Console.WriteLine("State: " + session.ConnectionState);
            Console.WriteLine("Logon Time: " + session.LoginTime);
        }
    }
```

But I am unable to identify the session name of the user, means weather he is in a console connect or RDP user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
new TerminalServicesManager()
.GetLocalServer()
.GetSession(SessionId)
.WindowStationName
.ToString();
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue