# Detect whether an application's user is currently active in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2

In Windows Server 2008 R2, the Task Manager shows that users are either "Active" or "Disconnected", but applications launched by a user will continue to run when they are Disconnected.

Is there a way in .NET for an application to detect if the user that launched it is Disconnected?

Comment: take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132620/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-logged-in-connected-users-in-net

Comment: I tried it, but all it returns are empty strings.

Comment: Okay, I got it working.  Thanks, it's what I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you retrieve a list of logged-in/connected users in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132620/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-logged-in-connected-users-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the code from this related question: [How do you retrieve a list of logged-in/connected users in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132620/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-logged-in-connected-users-in-net)

I changed the code slightly to create static class, with a method that would check the active users against the current user's name and return true if the current user is active, false if they're disconnected.